# Merging two javascript array objects that share the same property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two javascript objects, as below.

```js
obj1 = {
  sdfjjweifh: {
    user: "bob@bob.com",
    id: "10"
  },
  fjemsnduci: {
    user: "fred@fred.com",
    id: "20"
  },
  dhcnwodpcu: {
    user: "joe@joe.com",
    id: "30"
  }
};

obj2 = [{
  Name: "Bob",
  Id: "10"
}, {
  Name: "Fred",
  Id: "20"
}, {
  Name: "Joe",
  Id: "30"
}];
```

I want to combine them where the "id" fields match with this result:

```js
obj1 = {
  sdfjjweifh: {
    user: "bob@bob.com",
    id: "10",
    Name: "Bob"
  },
  fjemsnduci: {
    user: "fred@fred.com",
    id: "20",
    Name: "Fred"
  },
  dhcnwodpcu: {
    user: "joe@joe.com",
    id: "30",
    Name: "Joe"
  }
};
```

What is the simplest way to go about that with pure javascript/ES6?

I've found a lot of things close to this, but can't quite put the pieces together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `forEach()` loop on the keys of `obj1` so that for each property of `obj1` you can find the corresponding matching object in array `obj2`:

```js
var obj1 = {
  sdfjjweifh: {
    user: "bob@bob.com",
    id: "10"
  },
  fjemsnduci: {
    user: "fred@fred.com",
    id: "20"
  },
  dhcnwodpcu: {
    user: "joe@joe.com",
    id: "30"
  }
};

var obj2 = [{
  Name: "Bob",
  Id: "10"
}, {
  Name: "Fred",
  Id: "20"
}, {
  Name: "Joe",
  Id: "30"
}];

Object.keys(obj1).forEach((key) => {
  var existObj2 = obj2.find(({Id}) => obj1[key].id === Id);
  if(existObj2){
    obj1[key].Name = existObj2.Name
  }
});
console.log(obj1);
```

Comment: Works brilliantly, and is fairly concise. Thanks!

Comment: @user11015833 glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Use `for..in` to loop over the object and get id from each of the object. Then use array `findIndex` to get the index of object from the array where `Id` matches. If Id matches then get its name from the array and add a new key in the object

```js
let obj1 = {
  sdfjjweifh: {
    user: "bob@bob.com",
    id: "10"
  },
  fjemsnduci: {
    user: "fred@fred.com",
    id: "20"
  },
  dhcnwodpcu: {
    user: "joe@joe.com",
    id: "30"
  }
};

let obj2 = [{
  Name: "Bob",
  Id: "10"
}, {
  Name: "Fred",
  Id: "20"
}, {
  Name: "Joe",
  Id: "30"
}];


for (let keys in obj1) {
  if (obj1[keys].hasOwnProperty('id')) {
    let keyIndex = obj2.findIndex(function(item) {
      return item.Id === obj1[keys].id
    });
    if (keyIndex !== -1) {
      obj1[keys].Name = obj2[keyIndex].Name
    }
  }
}
console.log(obj1)
```